# Custom HTMLElement not bubbling click event

Tags: dom-events

I am dabbling with customerElements:

```
customElements.define('state-button',
                    class extends HTMLElement {
                        constructor(...args) {
                            super(...args);
                            this.state = 0;                      
                            let o=this;                            
                            this.t = {
                                0:"<button class='btn btn-info'>"+(o.innerHTML)+"</button>",
                                1:"<button class='btn btn-warning'>Are you sure???</button>",
                                2:"<button class='btn btn-danger'>Last chance....</button>"
                            };
                            this.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick,{capture:false});
                        }
                        connectedCallback() {
                            this.setAttribute("data-toggle", "modal");
                            this.setAttribute("data-target", "#confirmModal");
                            this.setAttribute("data-jc_id", this.getAttribute("data-id"));
                            this.render();
                        }
                        render() {
                            console.debug("state", this.state);
                            this.innerHTML=this.t[this.state];
                        }
                        handleClick(event) {                            
                            this.state = (this.state+1) % 3;
                            this.render();                            
                        }
                        setState(state) {
                            this.state = state;
                            this.render();
                        }
                    }
                );
```

This is just me testing how it works. The button is supposed to change state AND open modal Bootstrap4 window. But the modal never gets triggered.
If I add `super.click();` inside `handleClick()` it will change state twice (as the event is triggered again).

If I do not `addEventListener` the Bootstrap 4 modal window triggers just fine. So it appears my event is stopping other events.
`return true;` at the end of `handleClick` has no effect.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it to the same effect. But I am sure it is not the correct way of doing it.
When I add the eventlistener  `this.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick,{once:true});` it will be removed once triggered. This will cause the bootstrap 4 modal window to trigger as well.
Then at the end of `handleClick` I just add the click event as above again.
As I said - it is a workaround.
I am still interested in why my event stops other click events....